# Entity Framework to custom object that contains a list of another object

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve a custom object from the C# Entity Framework.

I have this output coming from the database.

[image]

I am trying to get it into the following JSON encoded format.

```
{
    DT_RowId: 50-1, 
    donor: "0111158",
    serial_number: "0111158-2030RV-001",
    status: "Released",
    location:"Finished Goods",
    ext_dt: "08/2019",
    qty: "1",
    new_locations: [
        {
            "location_id":6,
            "location_name":"Post Sterilization Quarantine2"
        },
        {
            "location_id":5,
            "location_name":"Post Sterilization Quarantine1"
        },
        {
            "location_id":18,
            "location_name":"Material Review Board"
        }               
    ]
}
```

Here is what I have so far...but I am running into a road block on how to build the new_locations list.

```
        var details = from entity in db.GetInventoryMoveDeatils(id, username)
                      select new
                      {
                          DT_RowId = entity.DT_RowId,
                          donor = entity.donor,
                          serial_lot = entity.SERIAL_NUMBER,
                          status = entity.status,
                          location = entity.location,
                          ext_dt = entity.ext_dt,
                          qty = entity.qty
                      };

        return Json(new { data = details }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I am not sure what keywords to search for, because I am not sure what this is called in a LINQ query.  So all of my search results are not returning anything helpful.  I am willing to research it, but need some help with the key words that I should be searching for.

The data for the `new_locations` array is contained within the database results under the `ALLOWABLE_LOCATION` and `ALLOWABLE_LOCATION_SYSID`. I could run two separate LINQ queries and join them on the `DT_RowId` key. There are X number of rows with the different locations that are allowed.

Comment: To fetch`new_locations`, you should use `Include` if there are relationship between tables. If no, then write another linq query (you don't need to fetch the data using ToList() -- IQueryable should  do the trick) and do the `join` between first and second set. Now about having `new_locations` as part of entity --- for that you can do the apply `GroupBy` on `DT_RowId` as you have multiple records for it and select the required columns along with collection of locations.

Comment: what values are you looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
 var details = from entity in db.GetInventoryMoveDeatils(id, username)
               group entity by entity.DT_RowId in groupedData
        select new 
        {   
            DT_RowId = groupedData.key,
                          donor = groupedData.Select(x => x.donor ).FirstOrDefault(),
                          serial_lot =  groupedData.Select(x => x.SERIAL_NUMBER).FirstOrDefault()
                          status = groupedData.Select(x => x.status).FirstOrDefault() 
                          location = groupedData.Select(x => x.location).FirstOrDefault() 
                          ext_dt = groupedData.Select(x => x.ext_dt).FirstOrDefault() 
                          qty = groupedData.Select(x => x.qty).FirstOrDefault() ,
            new_locations = groupedData.Where(x => x.DT_RowId == groupedData.key).Select( a => new 
                {
                    location_id = a.ALLOWABLE_LOCATION_SYSID,
                    location_name = a.ALLOWABLE_LOCATION
                }).ToList()
        }
```

Comment: The data for the new_locations array is contained within the database results under the ALLOWABLE_LOCATION and ALLOWABLE_LOCATION_SYSID.  I could run two separate LINQs queries and join them on the DT_RowId key.  There are X number of rows with the different locations that are allowed.